# How to run all tests (from across different packages) in one build gradle file?

Tags: java, testing, gradle

I'm trying to find a way to kick off all tests from across <s>all my services</s> a selected bunch of services. Couldn't find a similar thread, as most people seem to be asking about running one/many tests from within the scope of one package.

I tried running `gradle test --tests a.b.c.TestClass`, while being in package `x.y.z`, but that gave me the following error:

> No tests found for given includes: [a.b.c.TestClass](--tests filter)

Comment: Simply running `gradle test` from the root project does this. Is that not what you need?

Comment: My bad I should have clarified, there's a lot of services in the root project and I only want to to run the selected few.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the Gradle docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering). There are various ways of running only a selected set of tests using wildcard filters and otherwise. Very neatly documented in the page I have pointed to.

You may pass onefilter as a parameter to `--tests` or create a task with multiple filters in a `filter` block and run that task.

Comment: Would this work outside of root directory? Ideally, I wouldn't want to add any changes there.

Comment: @Brucio, I am not sure what you mean exactly by "outside root directory". but gradle commands are run from the directory where `build.gradle` is or a sub-directory (though I think there are ways to do it from other locations). The task you run from one project runs all the tasks with the same **in all sub-projects from there**. That is why you were getting the error you mentioned in your post.